# Direct Proof even and odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factoring

In trying to show that $n$ is even, is my final solution correct?

First: If $n$ is even then $n^3+n$ is even.
Since $n$ is even, then: $$n=2\cdot s$$
$$n^3+n = (2\cdot s)\cdot (2\cdot s)\cdot (2\cdot s) + 2\cdot s$$
      $$= 6\cdot s^3 + 2\cdot s$$

Answer (score 2):

Almost. It should be $8s^3$. Close, though! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it's (in essence) correct, beside the miscalculation with the $6\cdot s^3$ term. I'd write it this way, for presentation purposes:

---

Suppose $n$ is even. Thus, $\exists k \in {Z}$ such that $n=2k$.

$n=2k \implies n^3+n=(2k)^3+2k = 2(2^2k^3+k),$ where $(2^2k^3+k)=q \in Z.$

Thus, $q\in Z \implies \exists q \in Z$ such that $n^3+n = 2q.$

Therefore, $n^3+n$ is even.

---

Now, suppose we wanted to show that if $n$ is odd, then $n^3+n$ is even:

Suppose $n$ is odd. Thus, $\exists k \in {Z}$ such that $n=2k+1$.

$n=2k \implies n^3+n=(2k+1)^3+2k+1 $

$$= 8k^3+12k^2+8k+2,$$

$$= 2(4k^3+6k^2+4k+1),$$

where $$(4k^3+6k^2+4k+1)=q \in Z.$$

Thus, $q\in Z \implies \exists q \in Z$ such that $n^3+n = 2q.$

Therefore, $n^3+n$ is even.

Comment: How would present this suppose n was odd.

Comment: The proof would be similar, only we'd have to assume that $n=2k-1$ (or $n=2k+1$, if you prefer), and then, like above, show that there exists an integer $q$ such that $n^3+n$ could be factored into into $2q-1$ or $2q+1$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this part (2k)^3+2k = 2(2^2k^3+k).

Comment: I appended my answer so you could see the explanation

Comment: I know i shouldn't be saying Thank you but this really helped me understand a lot about discrete-math which i am new to.Thanks good sir

Comment: No harm in saying "thanks" in my book. You're welcome.

Comment: was revising this answer today and had problems understanding this dedcution n^3+n=(2k+1)^3+2k+1 $

$$= 8k^3+12k^2+8k+2,$$ 

$$= 2(4k^3+6k^2+4k+1),$$ would you mind just explaining this part

Comment: Where exactly are you finding a problem?

Comment: right here (2k+1)^3+2k+1 
$$= 8k^3+12k^2+8k+2,$$

Comment: It's correct- I verified it by hand and by Wolfram Alpha. Check your algebra very carefully; it's easy to miss terms.

Comment: Dont get me wrong I am not saying it is incorrect, i just dont understand how they are equivalent.

Comment: Try evaluating it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18437/discussion-between-it-ken-and-daonlybg).